# How else could we solve the congruence?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

How could I solve the congruence $6x \equiv 1 \pmod { 5^4}$?

I wanted to use the formula $x_n=\frac{5^4+1}{6}$, but calculating this number, we see that it is not integer.

How else could we solve the congruence?

Comment: dividing by 6 is the same as multiplying by the inverse of $6$ modulo $5^4.$

Answer (score 4):

$5^4=625\equiv1\pmod6$, so $5\cdot5^4\equiv5\pmod6$, and $5^5\equiv5\pmod6$, i.e., $6\mid 5^5+1$.

Now $5^5+1\equiv1\pmod{5^4}$, so you could just as well solve $6x\equiv5^5+1\pmod{5^4}$.

Comment: How do we get from the congruence $5^5+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$ to this one: $5^5+1 \equiv 1 \pmod {5^4}$ ? :/

Comment: Since $5^5=5\cdot5^4$, it is zero modulo $5^4$, therefore $5^5+1\equiv0+1\equiv1\pmod{5^4}$.

Comment: @evinda: We don't: that's a separate fact, for which Peter has given an explanation.

Comment: And how can we solve then this congruence: $6x \equiv 5^5+1 \pmod{5^4}$ ?

Comment: @evinda: Use the fact that $6\mid5^5+1$.

Answer (score 3):

You could note that $5^4-1=624$ is a multiple of $6$, in fact it is $6\cdot104$. This means that $$6\cdot104\equiv -1 \pmod{5^4}$$
or equivalently
$$6^{-1} \equiv -104 \pmod{5^4}$$

Multiplying both sides (of the original equation) by $-104$ then yields that

$$x\equiv -104 \pmod{5^4}.$$

Comment: How did you know that you should find $5^4-1$?
$$$$

Also, is there a general formula for the solution of the congruence: $6x \equiv 1 \pmod {5^n}$?

Comment: To be honest it was a bit of reverse engineering.

Comment: @evinda using Brian's method, first try to prove that $6\mid 5^{2k+1}+1$. Then, if $n$ is odd, this means that $(5^n+1)/6$ is an integer, and if $n$ is even $(5^{n+1}+1)/6$ is an integer. Both of these are inverses of 6 modulo $5^n$ whenever they are integers, so they will work in each respective case.

This would make the solution $x\equiv \frac{5^n+1}{6} \pmod{5^n}$ if $n$ is odd, and $x\equiv \frac{5^{n+1}+1}{6}$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: So, do I have to prove that $6 \mid 5^n+1, \forall n$, or have I understood it wrong?

But, if so, when $n=2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, isn't it like that?
$$$$
$5^{2k}+1=25^k+1 \equiv 1^k+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 6$